# PyCharm code inspection complains template file not found, how to fix?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, pycharm

I'm new to **PyCharm**, and I'm trying to use it for Django development. My app is structured like this:

```
bs3app/
├── __init__.py
├── templates
│   └── home.html
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

In `bs3app/views.py`, I get a warning:

> Template file 'home.html' not found

The source code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

The template file is there in `bs3app/templates/home.html`. The `home` view works correctly when I run the site. On the **Django Support** page of the project, **Enable Django Support** is on, and the **Django project root**, **Settings** and **Manage script** values are all correct.

So, why am I getting the warning? As per [this PyCharm doc page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/defining-template-directories.html), I can mark the template directories explicitly and then the warning goes away, but why do I *have to*? Why can't PyCharm figure them out automatically, given the `settings.py` file of the project?

The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/janosgyerik/djbootstrap), if you need to see other files.

Comment: Are you using the console within PyCharm (if it has one) ?

Comment: Okay it doesn't matter. Try doing this: "return render_to_response('/home.html')" (excluding the: " ") and see if the warning goes away. Your render_to_response is much simpler than any of mine, but I think the error may be as simple as a missing '/'.

Comment: @Joe no that doesn't help. The warning remains, and it breaks the site.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Just open the `project view` (view->tool windows -> project). There right-click on your `templates`-folder -> 'mark directory as'-> Template directory

Comment: I'll try in the morning. But there gotta be a better way. If django can see it correctly when I run the site, why can't pycharm. This is a pretty vanilla setup I have here. I'm wondering if I'm breaking some conventions or best practices in my code that causes this

Comment: My Pycharm 3 recognizes this folder. you could try to click `file-> invalidate caches`
I had a short look at your project. django 1.6 provides an option for creating project templates, see : 

http://www.maykinmedia.nl/blog/2013/jun/6/customizing-django-startproject-templates/

or have a look at this repo (very simple)

https://github.com/iliggio/django_project_template

you can start a project using `django-admin.py startproject --template '/path/to/projtemplate' projectname

or the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---template

Comment: ProfHase85 are you getting any warnings?

Comment: Sorry, you 're right. Also getting a warning unless I mark directory as template directory

Comment: I know this is not directly related to this problem but I think it might help somebody else who had my same problem: if you are writing a **Flask application**, the template language to select is **Jinja2**

Answer (score 21):

Try adding `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` to your settings file if you don't have it. I think PyCharm looks for it and doesn't load it from Django default settings. It solved my problem.

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Finally it recognizes my live templates (block + tab = {%block CARET %}{% endblock %}

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, but this one did.

Comment: Will this affect my actual django project ?

Comment: code with template_loader when deployed on Google app engine gives server error.

Comment: @Aseem `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` settings is removed from Django years ago (merged into `TEMPLATES` settings).

Comment: This answer perhaps needs some editing to let people know that it’s not a valid answer for new Django. Rookies like me end up spending quite some time on it

Answer (score 5):

If you have marked directory as template directory, but still get the warning, you can try changing the single quotes to double quotes

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html')
```

change to this:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How could that possibly help?

Comment: No idea why it helped, but mine was in double quotes. Changing it to single quotes made PyCharm happy...... Changing it back to double quotes, and it's still happy. I wonder if changing the quotes forces PyCharm to re-evaluate the path, and then it realizes that it's valid?

Comment: Changing it to double quotes then back to single quotes worked for me. Likely just needed to invalidate the cache on my project as it was a new import

Answer (score 3):

I am using PyCharm 2018.2. You can follow the next steps to mark a directory as a template directory, so PyCharm will not give you warnings, and you will be able to go to the template by pressing `cmd + B` (Mac) or `ctrl + B` (Windows/Linux):

1. Open the Settings dialog, and click the Project Structure page. You can use `cmd + ,` (on macOS), or by choosing  `File | Settings` (Windows/Linux)
   [image]
2. Choose the directory to be marked as a template root.
   [image]
3. Click on `Templates` on `Mark as`. In Mac you can also press `alt+T`.
   [image]
4. Click on OK to apply the changes you made.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue that was cause by forgetting to include my app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS. Adding my app to the list cleared the inspection.

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed when I assigned "Django project root" from settings to project destination.